# VBA to clear excel cells

Tags: excel, vba

```
Range("A4:A29").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A34:A59").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A64:A89").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A94:A119").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A124:A149").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A154:A179").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A184:A209").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A1").Select
```

I did the above coding to clear some boxes in excel, but it does not give me flexibility over range of boxes, what I want is to clear out any filled boxes in column A but if x mod 30 equals to zero to skip the next 3 and so on. I have used a similar code to fill up the boxes, see below:

```
With RegExp
    .Pattern = "\bT[0-9A-Z\(\)\-]+"
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    Set matches = .Execute(txt)
End With                                        

For Each Match In matches
    If x Mod 30 = 0 Then
        x = x + 4
    End If
    Cells(x, 1) = Match
    x = x + 1
    Cells(x, 1) = Match
    If x Mod 30 <> 0 Then
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next
```

If anyone could help me that would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bad idea (performance-wise) to first select the cell and then use Selection.ClearContents

Try this principle:

```
Range(Cells(x, 1), Cells(x + 29, 1)) = ""
```

This clears the contents of all Cells between x,1 and x+29,1

For your purpose it might be something like this (you might have to tweek the details because they are not clear from your post):

```
For x = 0 to 9 ' repeat however many times you want
    startingRow = x * 33 + 1
    Range(Cells(startingRow, 1), Cells(startingRow + 28, 1)) = ""
Next
```

Comment: Feel free to update your question or explain more what it's about and I'll have a look.

Comment: thanks it works but not what i wanted sorry if my question is vague.I wanted to clear out the cells thats been filled up by another button press. adn the cells filled up sequence were if x mod 30 = 0 then skip filling next 3 boxes if not then next one. So i want clear those texts too by a button press i.e reset button

Comment: Sorry, baash, I still don't understand what exactly you're trying to do. Do you just want to delete the contents for the entire row? Or do you want to delete the contents for all cells where RowNumber mod 30 is not 0, 1, or 2?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Thanks @E.Villager

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim lRow As Long
 Dim lCol As Long

 lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 For x = 4 To lRow

  If x Mod 30 = 0 Then
               x = x + 4
          End If
                Cells(x, 1) = ""

 Next

 End Sub
```